# Current big topics in quantitative finance for a research paper?

Tags: research, structured-finance

I am a final year student in quantitative finance. To get my degree, I need to write a research paper (approx. 50 pages) about any quantitative financial topic.

After getting my degree I would like to work as a structurer in an investment bank, on any product (with maybe a slight preference for the interest rate industry).

However, still being a student, I am not really aware of the current (or near future) big issues or debates that exist in that field, and to which I could make a contribution. Could you give me ideas of subjects of this kind, that I could use?

In addition, I would like these topics to be useful for the industry, in the sense that I would like to use my expertise to get a job. Ideally, it should not be too abstract and could be applied in a structurer job.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Same question. I usually go to http://arxiv.org/archive/q-fin or http://quantpedia.com/Blog to check for the latest papers. However I'm not sure whether they are about the current trends or not.

Comment: Unfortunately, this question doesn't fit very well in the StackExchange QA format. I would advise you to contact people in the industry most near to you (alumni, professors, etc).